# Inserting <span> tags between a specific sentence, keeping the original case

Tags: php, regex, preg-replace

I need to insert a span tag between a certain text from a string, but it should be case insensitive and keep the original case.

```
$string ="This is what this is";

echo str_replace("this is","[span]this is[/span]",$string);
```

Returns:

> This is what [span]**this is**[/span]

Expected:

> [/span]**This is**[/span] what [span]**this is**[/span]

I know the `str_replace` is not the good option for that, and ir might be probably handled by Regex, but I have no idea in which direction I should go. Thanks in advance for your help!

Comment: You may need `str_ireplace`, although it does a simple replacement and there is no backreference.

Answer (score 3):

Use [preg_replace](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-replace.php):

```
$string ="This is what this is";

echo preg_replace("/this is/i","[span]$0[/span]",$string);
```

**Explanation:**

```
/           : regex delimiter
   this is  : literally
/i          : regex delimiter, case insensitive
```

**Replacement:**

```
$0    : contains the whole match, ie "this is"
```